# IllegalArgumentException Xamarin Forms - Error

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

How to handle `IllegalArgumentException`?

> Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Error
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added :
>   Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat;

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

In Package Manager Console run (**Tools -> NuGet Package Manager -> Package Manger Console**):

```
Update-Package -reinstall
Update-Package
```

Keep in mind that this will reinstall all packages and then update them.

Comment: ,hanks @Wilson, i am already tried but  i got one more error i.e Xamarin.android.support.compat is not installed for targeting versions monoandroid 7.0 but in my machine having 6.0 version